# How to delete columns in pyspark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

```
>>> a
DataFrame[id: bigint, julian_date: string, user_id: bigint]
>>> b
DataFrame[id: bigint, quan_created_money: decimal(10,0), quan_created_cnt: bigint]
>>> a.join(b, a.id==b.id, 'outer')
DataFrame[id: bigint, julian_date: string, user_id: bigint, id: bigint, quan_created_money: decimal(10,0), quan_created_cnt: bigint]
```

There are two `id: bigint` and I want to delete one. How can I do?

Answer (score 197):

Reading the Spark documentation I found an easier solution.

Since version 1.4 of spark there is a function `drop(col)` which can be used in pyspark on a dataframe.

You can use it in two ways

1. `df.drop('age')`
2. `df.drop(df.age)`

[Pyspark Documentation - Drop](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.drop.html)

Comment: when the data size is large, collect() might cause heap space error. you can also create a new dataframe dropping the extra field by `ndf = df.drop('age')`

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to use `collect` for this operation so I removed it from this answer

Answer (score 162):

Adding to @Patrick's answer, you can use the following to drop multiple columns

```
columns_to_drop = ['id', 'id_copy']
df = df.drop(*columns_to_drop)
```

Comment: I had to reassign the drop results back to the dataframe:  df = df.drop(*columns_to_drop)

Comment: Note that you will not get an error if the column does not exist

Comment: I get an error saying `TreeNodeException: Binding attribute, tree: _gen_alias_34#34` after I drop a column, and use `.show()`

Comment: What the asterisk `*` means in `*columns_to_drop`?

Comment: The `*` is to unpack the list. `(*[a,b,c])` becomes `(a,b,c)`

Answer (score 36):

An easy way to do this is to user "`select`" and realize you can get a list of all `columns` for the `dataframe`, `df`, with `df.columns`

```
drop_list = ['a column', 'another column', ...]

df.select([column for column in df.columns if column not in drop_list])
```

Comment: Thank-you, this works great for me for removing duplicate columns with the same name as another column, where I use `df.select([df.columns[column_num] for column_num in range(len(df.columns)) if column_num!=2])`, where the column I want to remove has index 2.

Answer (score 24):

You can use two way:

1:
You just keep the necessary columns:

```
drop_column_list = ["drop_column"]
df = df.select([column for column in df.columns if column not in drop_column_list])
```

2: This is the more elegant way.

```
df = df.drop("col_name")
```

You should avoid the collect() version, because it will send to the master the complete dataset, it will take a big computing effort!

Answer (score 14):

You could either explicitly name the columns you want to keep, like so:

```
keep = [a.id, a.julian_date, a.user_id, b.quan_created_money, b.quan_created_cnt]
```

Or in a more general approach you'd include all columns except for a specific one via a list comprehension. For example like this (excluding the `id` column from `b`):

```
keep = [a[c] for c in a.columns] + [b[c] for c in b.columns if c != 'id']
```

Finally you make a selection on your join result:

```
d = a.join(b, a.id==b.id, 'outer').select(*keep)
```

Comment: I think I got the answer.  Select needs to take a list of strings NOT a list of columns.  So do this:

`keep = [c for c in a.columns] + [c for c in b.columns if c != 'id']`
`d = a.join(b, a.id==b.id, 'outer').select(*keep)`

Comment: Well, that should do exactly the same thing as my answer, as I'm pretty sure that `select` accepts either strings OR columns (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame). Btw, in your line `keep = ...` there's no need to use a list comprehension for `a`: `a.columns + [c for c in b.columns if c != 'id']` should achieve the exact same thing, as `a.columns` is already a `list` of strings.

Comment: @deusxmach1na Actually the column selection based on strings cannot work for the OP, because that would not solve the ambiguity of the `id` column. In that case you have to use the `Column` instances in `select`.

Comment: All good points.  I tried your solution in Spark 1.3 and got errors, so what I posted actually worked for me.  And to resolve the id ambiguity I renamed my id column before the join then dropped it after the join using the keep list.  HTH anyone else that was stuck like I was.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a little bit off topic, but here is the solution using Scala. Make an `Array` of column names from your `oldDataFrame` and delete the columns that you want to drop `("colExclude")`. Then pass the `Array[Column]` to `select` and unpack it.

```
val columnsToKeep: Array[Column] = oldDataFrame.columns.diff(Array("colExclude"))
                                               .map(x => oldDataFrame.col(x))
val newDataFrame: DataFrame = oldDataFrame.select(columnsToKeep: _*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to drop/select columns by slicing like this:

slice = data.columns[a:b]

data.select(slice).show()

Example:

```
newDF = spark.createDataFrame([
                           (1, "a", "4", 0), 
                            (2, "b", "10", 3), 
                            (7, "b", "4", 1), 
                            (7, "d", "4", 9)],
                            ("id", "x1", "x2", "y"))


slice = newDF.columns[1:3]
newDF.select(slice).show()
```

Use select method to get features column:

```
features = newDF.columns[:-1]
newDF.select(features).show()
```

Use drop method to get last column:

```
last_col= newDF.drop(*features)
last_col.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete column like this:

```
df.drop("column Name).columns
```

In your case :

```
df.drop("id").columns
```

If you want to drop more than one column you can do:

```
dfWithLongColName.drop("ORIGIN_COUNTRY_NAME", "DEST_COUNTRY_NAME")
```

Comment: Spark 2.4 (and least versions) doesn't accepts more than one column name.

Comment: Is it possible to drop columns by index ?

Comment: @seufagner it does just pass it as a list

Answer (score -1):

Consider 2 dataFrames:

```
>>> aDF.show()
+---+----+
| id|datA|
+---+----+
|  1|  a1|
|  2|  a2|
|  3|  a3|
+---+----+
```

and

```
>>> bDF.show()
+---+----+
| id|datB|
+---+----+
|  2|  b2|
|  3|  b3|
|  4|  b4|
+---+----+
```

To accomplish what you are looking for, there are 2 ways:

**1. Different joining condition.** Instead of saying aDF.id == bDF.id

```
aDF.join(bDF, aDF.id == bDF.id, "outer")
```

Write this:

```
aDF.join(bDF, "id", "outer").show()
+---+----+----+
| id|datA|datB|
+---+----+----+
|  1|  a1|null|
|  3|  a3|  b3|
|  2|  a2|  b2|
|  4|null|  b4|
+---+----+----+
```

This will automatically get rid of the extra the dropping process.

**2. Use Aliasing:** You will lose data related to B Specific Id's in this.

```
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import col
>>> aDF.alias("a").join(bDF.alias("b"), aDF.id == bDF.id, "outer").drop(col("b.id")).show()

+----+----+----+
|  id|datA|datB|
+----+----+----+
|   1|  a1|null|
|   3|  a3|  b3|
|   2|  a2|  b2|
|null|null|  b4|
+----+----+----+
```