# Join PySpark dataframe with a filter of itself and columns with same name

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I  have a `target` dataframe like this:

```
rdd_1 = sc.parallelize([(0,"A",2), (1,"B",1), (2,"A",2)])
rdd_2 = sc.parallelize([(0,223,"201603"), (1,3213,"201602"), (2,2321,"201601")])
df_tg = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_1, ["id", "route_a", "route_b"])
df_data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd_2, ["id", "cost", "date"])

 df_tg.show()

+---+-------+-------+
| id|route_a|route_b|
+---+-------+-------+
|  0|      A|      2|
|  1|      B|      1|
|  2|      A|      2|
+---+-------+-------+
```

and more information on another dataframe with some timestamps:

```
 df_data.show()

+---+----+------+
| id|cost|  date|
+---+----+------+
|  0| 223|201603|
|  1|3213|201602|
|  2|2321|201601|
+---+----+------+
```

and I need to create new columns joining the dataframes, but by date:

```
df_data_m1 = df_data[df_data.date == "201603"]
df_data_m2 = df_data[df_data.date == "201602"]
df_data_m3 = df_data[df_data.date == "201601"]
```

and now I need to create new columns:

```
df = df_tg.join(df_data_m1, df_data_m1.id == df_tg.id)
```

but this generates the problem of [duplicated](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/876/is-there-a-better-method-to-join-two-dataframes-an.html) [columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29600673/how-to-delete-columns-in-pyspark-dataframe) that we have to drop and rename the column so we will not overwrite the previous dates:

```
 df = df_tg.join(df_data_m1, df_data_m1.id == df_tg.id).drop(df_data_m1.id).withColumnRenamed("cost", "cost_201603")
 df = df.join(df_data_m2, df_data_m2.id == df_tg.id).drop(df_data_m2.id).withColumnRenamed("cost", "cost_201602")
```

and we have to do this for each column, for each month, so that's a lot of code, even if we write a UDF to handle this. Is there a way to do it directly?

Comment: You should provide some data that is easy to copy / paste so that we can try to practice fixing your problem given your exact use case.

Comment: Done. Hopefully it will be easier to understand now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to deal with duplicate columns is not to generate these at all. If all you have is equi-joins all you need is correct `join`. Spark provides special syntax for cases like this were you simply enumerate join columns:

```
tmp = df_tg.join(df_data, ["id"])
tmp.printSchema() 
## root
##  |-- id: long (nullable = true)
##  |-- route_a: string (nullable = true)
##  |-- route_b: long (nullable = true)
##  |-- cost: long (nullable = true)
##  |-- date: string (nullable = true)
```

On a side note the remaining part of your code smell fishy. If `DataFrame` is not partitioned each filter like this:

```
df_data[df_data.date == "201603"]
```

requires a linear scan over all records.

It is not exactly clear for me what is your goal but if you want to separate data for writes you can use `partitionBy` method in supported writers:

```
tmp.write.partitionBy("date")
```

In other cases [pivoting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35676755/1560062) can be a better choice.

Finally if you plan to apply some aggregations it makes more sense to shuffle once (`groupBy` or [`repartition`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32920122/1560062)) than doing this on separated data.